# SSDT/LocalDB data and log file location for PRIMARY filegroup when other filegroups defined explicitly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, localdb

I've noticed problematic behavior for SQL Server Data Tools (tested with 14.0.61707) when a SQL Server Database Project (`*.sqlproj`) contains at least one explicitly defined filegroup: namely, the default PRIMARY filegroup's `.mdf` file as well as the `.ldf` file (transaction log) are *not* placed in the expected instance-specific location of `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\{instance name}`, but rather are placed in `%USERPROFILE%` (e.g., `C:\Users\fbar`) directly.

By contrast, a SQL Server Database Project containing *only* the PRIMARY filegroup -- i.e., with no explicit filegroups or files defined at all -- places its .mdf and .ldf files in the correct instance-specific location above (`...\Instances\{instance name}`).

This behavior causes issues when switching a database to target a different instance (e.g., from `Projects` to `ProjectsV12`), as the data files previously written to `%USERPROFILE%` are in the way when the new data files attempt to be written on the new instance. This then results in errors like this:

```
Deploy error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5170, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 Cannot create file 'C:\Users\fbar\Testing.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
```

This is especially problematic on our CI servers where files get created in locations that users cannot access directly, and it requires administrators to clean them up.

The only solution I've come up with is to add a new "Filegroup File" item to the project, defining a file for the PRIMARY filegroup, like so:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE
(
    NAME = [PRIMARY],
    FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_PRIMARY.mdf'
) TO FILEGROUP [PRIMARY]
```

This seems to cause the `.mdf` and `.ldf` for PRIMARY to be created in the desired instance-specific location.

So, is this a bug in SSDT? Is there another way around it?